# Detect the main vein of the leaves

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, image-processing

Is there any a better algorithm to detect just the main or primary vein of the leaves  such as cauliflower leaves and ignore the secondary vein ones?.I am only interested in main vein I've tried the blur filter to reduce the secondary veins in different size of mask (3,5,7,..)  worked for some samples but the rest not because  I'm working on hundred of samples.
This is one of my samples:http://labs.tineye.com/color/34e494bcce475bb443971e6b2715084d52d0db24?ignore_background=False&ignore_interior_background=False&width=250&height=187&scroll_offset=483.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have access to leaf segmentation, e.g. you want to find the main vein of a single leaf, or of each leaf over the whole image?

Comment: Actually, I want to detect most of main veins to consider them as lines and use them to get the center of the plant.Yes Micka.

Comment: is the provided image your full resolution? can you add edge images to get an impression of the data you are working with?!? if possible explain your current method in detail or pseudo code.

Comment: My algorithm to detect veins of the plant:
1- Apply Gaussian Blur with mask 5*5 to the original image 
1- Convert the color image (blurred image) to Hsv.
2-Spilt the HSV to h, s, and v.
3- I chose s channel and applied threshold (s<35)
4-Now I  got most of veins include secondary veins .

Comment: Can you post an image with your results?

Comment: http://labs.tineye.com/color/09ad9e51ae89e6df7a9d5bd6698badd637fb53dc?ignore_background=True&width=250&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True&height=186 .I got this result because I changed the threshold value.

Comment: I don't want to change the threshold whenever I want to test another sample and sometimes I lose some main veins. So that is why I'm looking for better algorithm.

Comment: can you show a result with some standard threshold which gives you the wanted primary veins and some secondary veins for all images. So I mean a result which you want to improve.

Comment: This is another sample: http://labs.tineye.com/color/4a45fc59b72d0ac25b30c3e051d14a633d5781d1?ignore_background=True&width=249&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True&height=172

Comment: Could you explain why you rejected an edit where the images were added to the post rather than as external links, please? The comments asked for images. You have a lot more chance of getting a useful answer if the post is complete (i.e create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) without having to go to third party sites etc.

Comment: Actually, I couldn't  edit all your correction, especially, the images. It says that I can't post my images directly  because I don't have enough reputation  .Anyway,I apologize about that .